# Does the human eye see things at twice the distance in a mirror?

Tags: vision, human-eye

If I'm standing 3ft away from a mirror and looking at something in it that is behind me but 5ft away from the mirror, do my eyes see that object as 3ft? Or 8?

Comment: 8 feet. You can do [ray tracing](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Map%3A_University_Physics_III_-_Optics_and_Modern_Physics_(OpenStax)/02%3A_Geometric_Optics_and_Image_Formation/2.02%3A_Images_Formed_by_Plane_Mirrors) for a plane mirror and see that the image will "appear" at an equivalent distance behind the mirror. The light hits your eyes at the same angle as if the object really were that far away.

Comment: As a side note, this is why nearsighted people will have trouble seeing distant objects in mirrors, even if they put their eyes close to the mirror.

Comment: @user137 don't answer questions in the comments. With the link attached and a little more elaboation on the answer it's a good answer imo

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be primarily about optics rather than biology.